# Create Facebook style notifications (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using the standard laravel notifications setup and it's working great but now I want to customize it further.

How can I get the Facebook format for creating notifications? For example if a notification for comment on a post already exists, now instead of creating a new one, I would like to append to it, increment the count and update it.

**Basic use cases**

original notification:

`$user->name . ' left a comment on your post';`

updated notification:

`$user->name .','. $otherUser->name . ' and 3 others left a comment on your post';`

I don't have any codes yet because I don't really know from where to start making something like this.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this without code. Personally, I would try to avoid updating a post's comment counts in the database every time a comment is submitted.

I'm making the assumption that you would be adding a separate update query to posts every time a comment is created. That would work, but the number of additional update queries could add up if there end up being a lot of comments.

Depending on the query, I would try to use a groupBy() to get the totals you're looking for at query time instead of running the extra update queries.

This all depends though on the structure of the application and database, so take all this with a grain of salt.